# Why does StateFul DoFn require KV tuple in python?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read Json object from Pubsub, and after converting it to Python Dict, if I try to pass the Dict in my Stateful DoFn, I encounter this error. 'Input value to a stateful DoFn or KeyParam must be a KV tuple; '
Why is it required to assign a key to my existing dict for stateful DoFn?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but I had a recent similar experience with KV objects (also working from PubSub!) so I will try to answer your question... Maybe you - or someone - will find it useful! ;)

### Input elements in Apache Beam [`Stateful DoFn`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.8.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=_statedofnparam#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.StateParam)

Stateful DoFn have to work with specific data structure:

- you can work with simple types (int, string, a "simple" list...)
- when you have to use more complex data structure (such as a nested json/dict that you can get from a PubSub message), you have to implement it
  with a KV data structure.

### What is a KV tuple ?

`KVs` are [Java data structures](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/KV.html) that have been implemented in Python using a "collection of key-value pairs" (ie a collection of tuples of 2 elements where one plays the role of a key and the other one of the value).

Finally, why do you need to do that, if that's your question...

- a bit of logic: some part of the implementation requires an immutable key/value pair.
- a bit of an historical accident: the whole mechanics was first implemented in Java and they needed to translate those Java KV Class into Python data structures. Using dictionary which provides immutability only for its keys could have probably probably used too but it would have made the translation of the Jave code more difficult... But it's only my guess.

Last but not least, be aware that, in my experience, you can't even put a dict into a KV instance!

```py
#list of KVs without JSON values: OK
input_good = [(("json", "val"), ("table_name", "one")),
              (("json", "val"), ("table_name", "two"))]

#list of KVs with JSON values: KO!
input_bad = [(("json", {"test":"test"}), ("table_name", "one")),
             (("json", {"test":"test"}), ("table_name", "two"))]
```

I advice you to keep your PubSub message as a string or a byte and to translate it afterwards.